# Get root dialog in Python on Mac OS X, Windows?

Tags: python, windows, macos, wxpython, root

How would I go about getting a privilege elevation dialog to pop up in my Python app? I want the UAC dialog on Windows and the password authentication dialog on Mac.

Basically, I need root privileges for part of my application and I need to get those privileges through the GUI. I'm using wxPython. Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it through python script in OSX. Under some Unix-like OS (OS X included), the scripts (like shell, perl, python, ...) could not be granted to call chown/chgrp which gives you other privileges.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you cannot get the UAC dialog without starting a new process, and you cannot even start that process with CreateProcess.

The UAC dialog can be brought about by running another application that has the appropriate manifest file - see [Running compiled python (py2exe) as administrator in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195109/running-compiled-python-py2exe-as-administrator-in-vista) for an example of how to do this with py2exe.

You can also programatically use the runas verb with the win32 api ShellExecute http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx - you can call this by using ctypes http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/ which is part of the standard library on python 2.5+ iirc.

Sorry don't know about Mac. If you give more detail on what you want to accomplish on Windows I might be able to provide more specific help.

Answer (score 4):

I know the post is a little old, but I wrote the following as a solution to my problem (running a python script as root on both Linux and OS X).

I wrote the following bash-script to execute bash/python scripts with administrator privileges (works on Linux and OS X systems):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Specify executable"
    exit 1
fi

EXE=$1

available(){
    which $1 >/dev/null 2>&1
}

platform=`uname`

if [ "$platform" == "Darwin" ]; then
    MESSAGE="Please run $1 as root with sudo or install osascript (should be installed by default)"
else
    MESSAGE="Please run $1 as root with sudo or install gksu / kdesudo!"
fi

if [ `whoami` != "root" ]; then

    if [ "$platform" == "Darwin" ]; then
        # Apple
        if available osascript
        then
            SUDO=`which osascript`
        fi

    else # assume Linux
        # choose either gksudo or kdesudo
        # if both are avilable check whoch desktop is running
        if available gksudo
        then
            SUDO=`which gksudo`
        fi
        if available kdesudo
        then
            SUDO=`which kdesudo`
        fi
        if ( available gksudo && available kdesudo )
        then
            if [ $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = "KDE" ]; then
                SUDO=`which kdesudo`;
            else
                SUDO=`which gksudo`
            fi
        fi

        # prefer polkit if available
        if available pkexec
        then
           SUDO=`which pkexec`
        fi

    fi

    if [ -z $SUDO ]; then
        if available zenity; then
            zenity --info --text "$MESSAGE"
            exit 0
        elif available notify-send; then
            notify-send "$MESSAGE"
            exit 0
        elif available xmessage notify-send; then
            xmessage -buttons Ok:0 "$MESSAGE"
            exit 0
        else
            echo "$MESSAGE"
        fi
    fi

fi

if [ "$platform" == "Darwin" ]
then
    $SUDO -e "do shell script \"$*\" with administrator privileges"
else
    $SUDO $@
fi
```

Basically, the way I set up my system is that I keep subfolders inside the bin directories (e.g. /usr/local/bin/pyscripts in /usr/local/bin), and create symbolic links to the executables. This has three benefits for me:

(1) If I have different versions, I can easily switch which one is executed by changing the symbolic link and it keeps the bin directory cleaner (e.g. /usr/local/bin/gcc-versions/4.9/, /usr/local/bin/gcc-versions/4.8/, /usr/local/bin/gcc --> gcc-versions/4.8/gcc)

(2) I can store the scripts with their extension (helpful for syntax highlighting in IDEs), but the executables do not contain them because I like it that way (e.g. svn-tools --> pyscripts/svn-tools.py)

(3) The reason I will show below:

I name the script "run-as-root-wrapper" and place it in a very common path (e.g. /usr/local/bin) so python doesn't need anything special to locate it. Then I have the following run_command.py module:

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.spawn import find_executable

#===========================================================================#

def wrap_to_run_as_root(exe_install_path, true_command, expand_path = True):
    run_as_root_path = find_executable("run-as-root-wrapper")

    if(not run_as_root_path):
        return False
    else:
        if(os.path.exists(exe_install_path)):
            os.unlink(exe_install_path)

        if(expand_path):
            true_command = os.path.realpath(true_command)
            true_command = os.path.abspath(true_command)
            true_command = os.path.normpath(true_command)

        f = open(exe_install_path, 'w')
        f.write("#!/bin/bash\n\n")
        f.write(run_as_root_path + " " + true_command + " $@\n\n")
        f.close()
        os.chmod(exe_install_path, 0755)

        return True
```

In my actual python script, I have the following function:

```
def install_cmd(args):
    exe_install_path = os.path.join(args.prefix, 
                                    os.path.join("bin", args.name))

    if(not run_command.wrap_to_run_as_root(exe_install_path, sys.argv[0])):
        os.symlink(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]), exe_install_path)
```

So if I have a script called TrackingBlocker.py (actual script I use to modify the /etc/hosts file to re-route known tracking domains to 127.0.0.1), when I call "sudo /usr/local/bin/pyscripts/TrackingBlocker.py --prefix /usr/local --name ModifyTrackingBlocker install" (arguments handled via argparse module), it installs "/usr/local/bin/ModifyTrackingBlocker", which is a bash script executing

```
/usr/local/bin/run-as-root-wrapper /usr/local/bin/pyscripts/TrackingBlocker.py [args]
```

e.g.

```
ModifyTrackingBlocker add tracker.ads.com
```

executes:

```
/usr/local/bin/run-as-root-wrapper /usr/local/bin/pyscripts/TrackingBlocker.py add tracker.ads.com
```

which then displays the authentification dialog needed to get the privileges to add:

```
127.0.0.1  tracker.ads.com
```

to my hosts file (which is only writable by a superuser).

If you want to simplify/modify it to run only certain commands as root, you could simply add this to your script (with the necessary imports noted above + import subprocess):

```
def run_as_root(command, args, expand_path = True):
    run_as_root_path = find_executable("run-as-root-wrapper")

    if(not run_as_root_path):
        return 1
    else:
        if(expand_path):
            command = os.path.realpath(command)
            command = os.path.abspath(command)
            command = os.path.normpath(command)

        cmd = []
        cmd.append(run_as_root_path)
        cmd.append(command)
        cmd.extend(args)

        return subprocess.call(' '.join(cmd), shell=True)
```

Using the above (in run_command module):

```
>>> ret = run_command.run_as_root("/usr/local/bin/pyscripts/TrackingBlocker.py", ["status", "display"])
>>> /etc/hosts is blocking approximately 16147 domains
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem on Mac OS X. I have a working solution, but it's not optimal. I will explain my solution here and continue looking for a better one.

At the beginning of the program I check if I'm root or not by executing

```
def _elevate():
    """Elevate user permissions if needed"""
    if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
        try:
            os.setuid(0)
        except OSError:
            _mac_elevate()
```

os.setuid(0) will fail if i'm not already root and that will trigger _mac_elevate() which relaunch my program from the start as administrator with the help of osascript. osascript can be used to execute applescript and other stuff. I use it like this:

```
def _mac_elevate():
    """Relaunch asking for root privileges."""
    print "Relaunching with root permissions"
    applescript = ('do shell script "./my_program" '
                   'with administrator privileges')
    exit_code = subprocess.call(['osascript', '-e', applescript])
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

The problem with this is if I use subprocess.call as above I keep the current process running and there will be two instances of my app running giving two dock icons. If I use subprocess.Popen instead and let the non-priviledged process die instantly I can't make use of the exit code, nor can I fetch the stdout/stderr streams and propagate to the terminal starting the original process.

Comment: The subprocess execution fails immediately with the following error (and I was never actually prompted for a password) `0:63: execution error: The administrator username or password was incorrect. (-60007)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `osascript` with `with administrator privileges` is actually just Apple Script wrapping a call to [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg).

But you can call `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` directly from Python3 with ctypes.

For example, the following parent script `spawn_root.py` (run as a non-root user) spawns a child process `root_child.py` (run with root privileges).

The user will be prompted to enter their password in the OS GUI pop-up. Note that this will *not* work on a headless session (eg over ssh). It *must* be run inside the GUI (eg Terminal.app).

After entering the user's password into the MacOS challenge dialog correctly, `root_child.py` executes a soft shutdown of the system, which requires root permission on MacOS.

### Parent (spawn_root.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, ctypes
import ctypes.util
from ctypes import byref

sec = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("Security"))

kAuthorizationFlagDefaults = 0
auth = ctypes.c_void_p()
r_auth = byref(auth)
sec.AuthorizationCreate(None,None,kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,r_auth)

exe = [sys.executable,"root_child.py"]
args = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(exe))()
for i,arg in enumerate(exe[1:]):
  args[i] = arg.encode('utf8')

io = ctypes.c_void_p()

sec.AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth,exe[0].encode('utf8'),0,args,byref(io))
```

### Child (root_child.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    f = open( "root_child.out", "a" )

    try:
        os.system( "shutdown -h now" )
        f.write( "SUCCESS: I am root!\n" )
    except Exception as e:
        f.write( "ERROR: I am not root :'(" +str(e)+ "\n" )

    f.close()
```

#### Security Note

Obviously, any time you run something as root, you need to be very careful!

`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` is deprecated, but it *can* be used safely. But it can also be used unsafely!

It basically boils down to: do you actually know what you're running as root? If the script you're running as root is located in a Temp dir that has world-writeable permissions (as a *lot* of MacOS App installers have done historically), then any malicious process could gain root access.

To execute a process as root safely:

1. Make sure that the permissions on the process-to-be-launched are root:root 0400 (or writeable only by root)
2. Specify the absolute path to the process-to-be-launched, and don't allow any malicious modification of that path

##### Sources

1. https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky/blob/master/esky/sudo/sudo_osx.py
2. https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/14
3. https://www.jamf.com/blog/detecting-insecure-application-updates-on-macos/