# Running compiled python (py2app) as administrator in Mac

Tags: python, privileges, sudo, administrator, py2app

After looking at [Running compiled python (py2exe) as administrator in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195109/running-compiled-python-py2exe-as-administrator-in-vista) I was wondering if there's an easy way to get the Mac Authentication dialog in Python (specifically py2app)

I know mac has the built in Authentication services too http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html

Also, I know I could do something like this:

```
os.system("""osascript -e 'do shell script "<commands here>"  with administrator privileges'""")
```

but was wondering if there was a built in way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell there was a Python Egg for doing this, but it's been unsupported by the author for several years now