# Creating an exe with pyInstaller that uses UAC

Tags: python, uac, pyinstaller

I have a python script which I would like to create an exe from, but It requires administrator privaleges. I would like to compile my script with pyInstaller, but I don't know if it has an option to enable UAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the platform SDK there is a file called MT. exe which can embed manifests into an exe (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195109/running-compiled-python-py2exe-as-administrator-in-vista):)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try py2exe?
All code will be write on Linux, and compile to .exe on Windows 7 x64.

All work good and without administrator privaleges.

[py2exe official site](http://www.py2exe.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like the executable to be light (pyInstaller's single file exe feature) and I would like to have it support code-signing and other out of the box stuff