# Python windows task to run with admin

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks, uac, taskscheduler

I am looking for some Python code to create a Windows Task in the Task Scheduler, it needs to run at start & have the highest permissions level (admin).

```
// description of your code here
Uses the new COM Task Scheduler Interface to create a new disabled scheduled task, then run it once as part of a script. Use this to launch interactive tasks, even remotely.
import win32com.client
computer_name = "" #leave all blank for current computer, current user
computer_username = ""
computer_userdomain = ""
computer_password = ""
action_id = "Test Task" #arbitrary action ID
action_path = r"c:\windows\system32\calc.exe" #executable path (could be python.exe)
action_arguments = r'' #arguments (could be something.py)
action_workdir = r"c:\windows\system32" #working directory for action executable
author = "Someone" #so that end users know who you are
description = "testing task" #so that end users can identify the task
task_id = "Test Task"
task_hidden = False #set this to True to hide the task in the interface
username = ""
password = ""
run_flags = "TASK_RUN_NO_FLAGS" #see dict below, use in combo with username/password
#define constants
TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY = 2
TASK_CREATE = 2
TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE = 6
TASK_ACTION_EXEC = 0
IID_ITask = "{148BD524-A2AB-11CE-B11F-00AA00530503}"
RUNFLAGSENUM = {
    "TASK_RUN_NO_FLAGS"              : 0,
    "TASK_RUN_AS_SELF"               : 1,
    "TASK_RUN_IGNORE_CONSTRAINTS"    : 2,
    "TASK_RUN_USE_SESSION_ID"        : 4,
    "TASK_RUN_USER_SID"              : 8 
}
#connect to the scheduler (Vista/Server 2008 and above only)
scheduler = win32com.client.Dispatch("Schedule.Service")
scheduler.Connect(computer_name or None, computer_username or None, computer_userdomain or None, computer_password or None)
rootFolder = scheduler.GetFolder("\\")
#(re)define the task
taskDef = scheduler.NewTask(0)
colTriggers = taskDef.Triggers
trigger = colTriggers.Create(TASK_TRIGGER_DAILY)
trigger.DaysInterval = 100
trigger.StartBoundary = "2100-01-01T08:00:00-00:00" #never start
trigger.Enabled = False
colActions = taskDef.Actions
action = colActions.Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC)
action.ID = action_id
action.Path = action_path
action.WorkingDirectory = action_workdir
action.Arguments = action_arguments
info = taskDef.RegistrationInfo
info.Author = author
info.Description = description
settings = taskDef.Settings
settings.Enabled = False
settings.Hidden = task_hidden
#register the task (create or update, just keep the task name the same)
result = rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(task_id, taskDef, TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, "", "", RUNFLAGSENUM[run_flags] ) #username, password
#run the task once
task = rootFolder.GetTask(task_id)
task.Enabled = True
runningTask = task.Run("")
task.Enabled = False
```

This code creates a task to run daily, but not at login & not as admin. Is there any way I can do this without requiring the UAC Prompt to open at startup?

EDIT: I am NOT looking to just make the program ask for administrator, as the prompt will popup, as specified above. I need it to have the highest execution level in the WINDOWS EVENT SCHEDULER to run at logon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running compiled python (py2exe) as administrator in Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195109/running-compiled-python-py2exe-as-administrator-in-vista)

Comment: @damagedCoda Nope. It's not about just admin; but highest execution level with the event scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching Google more thoroughly, I came across a command that does exactly what I need.

```
schtasks.exe /create /S COMPUTERNAME /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RL HIGHEST /SC ONLOGON /TN "Administrative OnLogon Script" /TR "cscript.exe \"Path\To\Script.vbs\""
```

All I need to do is replace the computer name, and program to execute and it makes the task perfectly. I can execute it in a elevated Python environment to create it.

Comment: That's an answer for Super User. This is a programming forum. I suggest leaving the question open for a few days in case someone will answer the question properly for this forum, in terms of using the COM API to set the run level and a logon trigger. (I've used the Task Scheduler's COM interface before, but I don't have time to look into this problem right now.)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea for you to build a Batch file running python and your script. Having done that there are a few things that you might want to try, i haven't personally had the time to try them out but here you go:

- Compile the `.BAT` file and make it an `.exe` once you do that i think you should be able to involve your task scheduler into the mix and get your code running whenever you need.
- If nothing works you can always mess around with your window's registry to allow your script to bypass the prompt using a Windows Registry Editor.

Do look it up before you execute as this is code I have found elsewhere, but it should do the trick:

---

```
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{E2F13B98-650F-47DB-845A-420A1ED34EC7}User\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
"LowRiskFileTypes"=".exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]
"LowRiskFileTypes"=".exe;.bat;.cmd;.vbs"
```

---