# Redirect Running Process Output to TextBox

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to Direct the output of any Process given the PID to a Textbox on my Form such as cmd.exe

I use the following code but nothing is happening:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private Int32 PID = 0;
    private Process process;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PID = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

        process = Process.GetProcessById(PID);

        process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
    }

    void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += e.Data;
    }

    private void FormMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        process.OutputDataReceived -= process_OutputDataReceived;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not possible.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4093252/34397

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with what you are trying to do is with the way you are using the event. The event only fires during async output operations.

You must set:

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Then use async read operations which will fire the event:

```
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

You should read the documentation for that event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx

Comment: No; the problem is that he isn't starting the process.

Comment: @SLaks From the look of it he is trying to access an already running process. Does that mean that it is indeed impossible?

Comment: AFAIK, that is impossible.