# Python run Popen( ) subprocess with elevated UAC privleges

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, uac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)

I'd like to execute a series of Java processes from a Python script, but I must run the Java with elevated UAC privleges (as Administrator) in order to get the results I'm expecting. My call right now is basically:

```
from subprocess import Popen
callme = 'java weka.doStuff' # Want this to run as Administrator
Popen(callme)
```

How do I force this process to run as administrator or with some sufficiently high of elevated UAC privileges?

Comment: Looks like the accepted answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script might solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot use Popen for that.

One option would be using `win32api.ShellExecute` and setting `runas` argument to Administrator.

Another option would be using [JPython](http://www.jython.org) itself...

Comment: JPython would not help, since it would all be in the same process.

Comment: Yeah, I just mentioned it because he was using Python to call out Java stuff.. ;)