# are global variables visible to subprocess and changable by subprocess?

Tags: python, variables, subprocess, global

A quick question for Python 2.7

Are global variables visible to a subprocess?

Can a subprocess change the values of global variables?

Many thanks.

Comment: if you want to run closely related Python code in child processes then consider [`multiprocessing` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html): it allows to send objects between processes just by passing them as function parameters (among other IPC methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The processes doesn't share the variables in a `general operating system` terms. Use some communication mechanism like message passing, shared memory etc to achieve the inter process communication.

Comment: Can you share an example of inter-process communication?

Comment: you can refer to this discussion for this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

No, global variables are not visible to a sub-process. Variables are private to each process. If you want to share variables then you need to use some form of inter-process communication.

Comment: Can you share an example of inter-process communication?

Comment: You can find oodles of info here: http://www.google.com/webhp?q=python%20ipc#q=python+ipc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest way is write those into a file and read from the file in another process, although this might take extra time.