# Interprocess communication in Lua with Example?

Tags: lua, ipc, interprocess

I have been struggling a lot to get this to work.
Can someone provide an example with any LUA api of 2 scripts that pass a message back and forth.

I have tried [Oil](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~maia/oil/), [lua-ipc](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-luaipc/tree/master/tests) and [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/).
But I face several missing libraries issues.

The ultimate goal is to pass a vector of numbers from one Lua process to another Lua process (with a different version of Lua) without going through disk.

Here is a similar [example in python of IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python) in a single file. Something similar in lua would be extremely helpful.

I really need an **example** as my knowledge in pipes or UDP/TCP is not strong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent would be to use luasocket. These examples come very close to the python example given. Here socket:receive() is used for the framing.

https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/samples/listener.lua

https://github.com/diegonehab/luasocket/blob/master/samples/talker.lua

Comment: definitely should use luasocket

Comment: For windows users, I found Luasocket very difficult to get compiled from the main repo so here is a link that has precompiled binaries https://github.com/alain-riedinger/luasocket