# Accessing lua_State from another application

Tags: c++, c, lua, hook, detours

Now imagine you have two programs with different lua instances. One is the main program, the second is the dll you coded for it.

In my question, I will name the main program as main, dll i child from now on. We load the child into the Main process, detouring it and somehow accessing lua_State.

My main question is, can we do lua_pcall or dofile via the lua_State we grab while the main program is running?

Sample code

Main program:

```
#include <lua.hpp>

bool loadFile(lua_State* L) {
    // run the Lua script
    luaL_dofile(L, "helloworld.lua");
    if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, eh) != 0)
    {
        std::string err = luaL_checkstring(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    // create new Lua state
    lua_State *lua_state;
    lua_state = luaL_newstate();

    loadFile(lua_state);
}
```

Child program:

```
#include <lua.hpp>
#include "hookingLibrary.h" 

typedef int(__fastcall* main_loadFile_Proto)(lua_State* L);
main_loadFile_Proto main_loadFile_Ptr;

lua_State * L lastState;
uint64_t main_loadFile_Addr = 0x0; 

int main_loadFile_Detour(lua_State* L) { 
    lastState = L;
    return main_loadFile_Ptr(L);
}

int main()
{
    // detouring etc.
    // I do not put detouring codes here. I am just declaring it as an 
    // opinion.
    
    HookingLibrary::hook((LPVOID)(uintptr_t)main_loadFile_Addr, &main_loadFile_Detour, (LPVOID*)&main_loadFile_Ptr);

    do{ 
       Sleep(100);
    }while(!lastState);

 
    // create new Lua state
    lua_State *lua_state;
    lua_state = lastState;

  
    // run the Lua script
    luaL_dofile(lua_state, "helloworld.lua");

    // close the Lua state
    lua_close(lua_state);
}
```

Comment: That depends: is "main" using Lua as a DLL or is it compiled into the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
Now imagine you have two programs with different lua instances. One is the main program, the second is the dll you coded for it.
```

This statement is not very clear, it depends on your expectations. I see 2 possible answers.

1. Create a DLL which implement some additional functions for Lua. The DLL library can be used later by the main program. In this case, there is only 1 instance of lua_state, there is only 1 Lua interpreter. This Lua interpreter may be created by the DLL or by the main function.

The interface of DLL is something like that:

```
#ifndef DLL_AUGMENTED
#define DLL_AUGMENTED

#include "lua.h"

lua_State *DLL_CreateAugmentedLuaInterpreter ();
void       DLL_FreeLuaInterpreter ();

#endif
```

And can be used by main:

```
#include "lua-augmented.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  lua_State *LuaState = DLL_CreateAugmentedLuaInterpreter ();

  // TODO: use the augmented Lua instance

  DLL_FreeLuaInterpreter(LuaState);

  return 0;
}
```

2. There is a need to have 2 Lua instances, as written `One is the main program, the second is the dll`. In this case, it's more difficult because a `IPC` Interprocess Communication need to be implemented with `sockets` or `pipes`. The best is to look for `LuaSocket` library.

[Interprocess communication in Lua with Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893558/interprocess-communication-in-lua-with-example)

Comment: so i cant i use lua interpret with injected dll?

Comment: You can, there is no problem. But you should be more clear about your expectations. Do you want `main` or `DLL` to create the Lua interpreter? What do you want `main` to do with the Lua interpreter? What do you want `DLL` to do with the Lua interpreter?

Comment: I want to create lua interpreter in main and access it from dll to run scripts. And my accessing method will be detour it because i have no access to main program, little type of hacking. Main is runnnig scripts all the time and i want to inject a dll and grab the lua state for run scripts...