# How to run a Kivy EventLoop in slave mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, event-loop

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075260/how-to-run-the-tornado-event-loop-alongside-a-kivy-gui)

I've discovered a `slave` property for the `runTouchApp` function that prevents the Kivy's event loop from running and forces to update it from somewhere else.
Here's a part of `app.py` where that property is used:

```
# we are in a slave mode, don't do dispatching.
if slave:
    return

try:
    if EventLoop.window is None:
        _run_mainloop()
    else:
        EventLoop.window.mainloop()
finally:
    stopTouchApp()
```

Here, if the app is not being run in slave mode, we have two choices on how to run the mainloop.
The first one, `_run_mainloop()` function works pretty straight-forward - it simply calls the `EventLoop.run()`, which in turn infinitely calls `EventLoop.idle()`.
That could lead us to believe that to keep the GUI running, we only need to call `idle`.

But then there's the second option, which calls the `kivy.core.window.WindowSDL`'s method `mainloop`.
That method works by calling another method, the `_mainloop` and this is where it gets interesting. The definition of said method is [**huge**](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py#L389) and it handles all sorts of events.

So okay, I ran my app in slave mode:

```
class TestApp(App):
    def start_event(self):
        pass

    def build(self):
        return Button(text = "hello")

    def run(self):
        # This definition is copied from the superclass 
        # except for the start_event call and slave set to True

        if not self.built:
            self.load_config()
            self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
            root = self.build()
            if root:
                self.root = root

        if self.root:
            Window.add_widget(self.root)

        window = EventLoop.window
        if window:
            self._app_window = window
            window.set_title(self.get_application_name())
            icon = self.get_application_icon()
            if icon:
                window.set_icon(icon)
            self._install_settings_keys(window)


        self.dispatch('on_start')
        runTouchApp(slave = True)
        self.start_event()  # Here we start updating
        self.stop()
```

Now, if I put this in the `start_event` method (by expectations):

```
def start_event(self):
    while True:
        EventLoop.idle()
```

Guess what, the app doesn't respond to touch events and freezes.
So I tried to call the Window's mainloop instead:

```
def start_event(self):
    EventLoop.window.mainloop()
```

And suddenly everything started working normally again. But the problem here is that such a call blocks forever, as it is an infinite loop, so there's no one-time update call like `EventLoop.idle`

How to keep the app running using such one-time calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is Python so assuming you want to stick to `WindowSDL` provider, you can always monkey patch this `mainloop` function so it won't be infinite:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import EventLoop

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    Button:
        text: 'test'
        on_press: print('doing my job')
''')

# https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py#L630
def mainloop(self):
    # replaced while with if
    if not EventLoop.quit and EventLoop.status == 'started':
        try:
            self._mainloop()
        except EventLoop.BaseException as inst:
            # use exception manager first
            r = EventLoop.ExceptionManager.handle_exception(inst)
            if r == EventLoop.ExceptionManager.RAISE:
                EventLoop.stopTouchApp()
                raise
            else:
                pass


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MyWidget(), slave=True)
    # monkey patch
    EventLoop.window.mainloop = mainloop
    while True:
        EventLoop.window.mainloop(EventLoop.window)
        print('do the other stuff')
        if EventLoop.quit:
            break
```

It's really hacky though and thus I'd not recommend running something like that in a production code.