# Python 3: what module to use for a fan-out interprocess communication?

Tags: python-3.x, ipc

I will have one python process `A` which will publish messages constantly, i.e. a "feed" if you will. I will have some other python processes `B`'s which will subscribe the "feed" and receive consume messages. Any `B` can start/stop at any time. A typical `B` will subscribe after its start-up and expect to receive messages published after its subscription. `B` will not send any message to `A` --- `A` should start to pump messages to `B`'s automatically up on their subscriptions. The many `B`'s don't have to subscribe at the same time --- they can come and go as they need, `A` will have to serve them without knowing when they will come and go. Let's say the number of `B`'s will be 1-10 for now (might be bigger later on if this model turn out working).

I wonder what python module provides the above functionality?

I have looked at `multiprocess` and `zmq` mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python). Apparently they are 1-to-1 connections. What I need (I think) is 1-to-many. Also in my case `B`'s won't send messages to `A` and `A` constantly push messages to `B`'s.

p.s. Python 3.x

Comment: ZeroMQ can do that. Check out http://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html

Comment: The publisher/subscriber model in `zmq` is exactly what I needed. Thank you @mkrieger1.