# Import variable from running python script

Tags: python

Is it possible to import a variable from a running python script into another script. Something like notebooks cells, but with scripts.
For example, load a neural network model and use it in another script so as not to load it every time it starts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables between files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files)

Comment: please elaborate  your sentence.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python

Comment: @Elvin Jafarov Clarified

Comment: You should look into the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module

Comment: use pickle module

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are a lot of ways doing it, here are some of the most popular from easy to harder:

1. Save the variable into a file, read it from the other script.
2. Save the variable into some kind of environment variable, use it from the second script.
3. Open a socket between the scripts and communicate through it.