# How to communicate and pass data from Python3 version to Python2.7 within pi

Tags: python

I am Trying to communicate from python3 to python2.7 within my Raspberry pi. I need python2.7 version as ROS( Robot operating System) is supported by python2.7 i have done almost all the codings. now i have to make communcation of mobile app to run the code which i made it throught firebasedata base, and firebasedatabase having a library pyrebase which is only supported by python3 version. Now i have to send data from python3 to python2.7 to run the whole process
Need help and thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Search for "inter-process communication", specially for Python, there is a lot of results, even on this very site, for example : [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)

You do not provide any details to indicate you need a specific answer, so I can just answer you that there are many approaches.

Comment: Basically i want to pass data from app to my robot. app is linked with pi using python 3 but my complete coding for robot is in python 2. i want strings from python 3 to be shared with my codes in python 2 and vice versa

Comment: secondly guide me, can i use built in SQLite database in python. to add or remove data from same database file, using python 2 and python 3.