# Retrieve information from another python script running in background

Tags: python, api, multiprocessing

I have two scripts:

- one continuosly comunicates with the gps module and refresh the gps time variable.
- the second one ask me when I want to view the gps time and prints it on the console.

How can I retrieve the gps_time variable of the first script (while it running in background) from the second script?

Comment: Try to write it to a file and read from it in another script. Adding code snippets can be helpful.

Comment: Let both scripts talk via sockets for instant sharing of gps points

Comment: I've just tried to write the time into a file and read it with the second script but this method is not reactive enough for my purpose. The comunication of the shared variable must be very fast!

Comment: Ok I will try to use the socket connection, can you post some link to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some socket programming.

Maybe you can get some idea from here:
[Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)

Official docs:
https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/socket.html