# Cannot create directory in Python (can do so manually..need admin permission)

Tags: python, windows

When I run `os.mkdir()` for a certain directory. I can't create a directory. However, I can do so manually (with admin dialog coming on before the creation, this is windows 7 btw). How would I run the `os.mkdir()` as admin?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is a scripting language. In order to have administrative rights, Python process has to be ran as admin as well.
And also, you might be interested in: [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)