# WindowsError: [Error 740] The requested operation requires elevation even after disabling UAC

Tags: python, windows-8, uac, elevation

I have disabled UAC and running my script in python.

```
command = "abcd.exe"
subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Also, I set the application `abcd.exe` from its property to run as admin.

Then I'm getting the following error:

> WindowsError: [Error 740] The requested operation requires elevation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)

Answer (score 14):

You could try using:

```
subprocess.call(["abcd.exe"], shell=True)
```

Basically the important part here is `shell=True`; if set to **False**, then you will get the following error.

> WindowsError: [Error 740]

Comment: Just follow this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is with using subprocess.Popen.

I also think that your question has already been answered here: 
[Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)

Comment: Thank you for replying.. :)
The solution in [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script) worked for me..