# How to executes cmd command using Python on Win 7 with admin

Tags: python, python-2.7

in python, i want to executes cmd command:

```
os.system("netsh interface set interface \"Local Area Connection\" disable")
```

to disconnect internet network. But, with my account, it report, interface name not register router. I think that, i need to executes  os.system as admin. But i don't know how to use it as admin! So, can you help me! Thank.

Comment: an easy way is to make an executable with pyinstaller and the --onefile option.  once the exe is created rename it... it will now require admin to run

Comment: this post has some insight : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script

Comment: Honestly, If possible don't use python for this task - powershell could do this better, it is designed for this kind of task

Answer (score 2):

To run command as admin on Windows, ou can use Windows [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command (I don't have access to a Windows machine right now, but perhaps..);

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'Your command'])
```