# Adding a line to Windows hosts file: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: python

I would like to add a line in my Windows hosts file via Python with this code:

```
fh = open("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hello.txt", "w")
fh.write("new line")
fh.close()
```

But I get this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hello.txt'`

It doesn't work even if my antivirus is disabled.

I don't know how to write a file as an administrator on a Windows machine.

Comment: First, if you want to *add* a line, you should use `fh = open("C:\..", "a")`. With `"w"` you truncate the file. Next to have admin permission on a windows machine, you must ... start the python interpretor as administrator !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is run your Python script with elevated privileges.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-python-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run Python as administrator, then it can write files in normally protected directories.

A command like

```
runas.exe /user:administrator "C:\Python34\python.exe myscript.py"
```

(edited for your actual Python installation and script paths) should work. You'll still need to provide a password.

Also, you should be using raw strings for Windows pathnames - you were just lucky that none of the backslashes preceded an escapable character:

```
fh = open(r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hello.txt", "a") # add, not overwrite
```

Answer (score -2):

This question is for Windows, but i thought i'd give an answer for Linux since future readers might be on Linux.

You can use **sudo**, given that you have the sufficient permissions in the /etc/sudoers file.

```
sudo python myscript.py
```

You will be prompted to enter your password.