# Accessing the Host File In A Python Program

Tags: python, file, admin, hosts

I created a program which modifies the hosts file in order to block some websites. But when I am running the programme, I am getting this error.
Btw I have created my Python file using Pycharm IDE and my intention is to run this script everytime open my PC using Task Scheduler. So please kindly do tell me what I should be running as the administrator. Is it like the Pycharm itself? Most importantly how do I give it Admin permissions permanently?

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts'
```

Please kindly tell me a way to fix this.

Comment: Can the Python script be run as admin?

Comment: A regular user doesn't have write permission to that file. You'll need to run your program as an administrator.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29770455/10230104

Comment: PyCharm is only IDE - it means editor with extra functions to develop code - and it has nothing to do with problem. After creating script you should run it without `PyCharm`. First you should check file's attributes - in console was function `attrib` for this. As I remeber long time ago it was in read-only mode and it needed only to remove this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows create a scheduled task on logon, and configure the task to run under a system account. The task could simply be run as a batch file and within the batch file you may run the below command. Ensure the task is set to run with administrator privileges in the task creation window

```
C:\PythonFolder\python.exe yourscript.py
```