# How to open command prompt in Administrator mode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, administrator

I'm a bit of a noob, so sorry in advance if I'm not doing this right.

I'm using python 3.6x

What I have so far that gets the command window open is

```
import os
os.open("start cmd")
```

but this comes up in the directory that I'm working from and not in administration mode.

I've also tried

```
import os
os.system("start /wait cmd /wait {tskill dwm}")
```

but that didn't work either. (`tskill dwm` is what I'm trying to get python to write in to command manager to fix a bug with windows' buttons not going away)

My overall goal is to just click this python script `Blah.py`  and have it restart the windows viewer or whatever it's called. Doing this clears the stuck buttons. Overall this is just an exercise in practicing python. I know I could just disable the button fade out and that would take care of the issue. I just figured this would be a good learning opportunity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open cmd with admin rights (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500369/open-cmd-with-admin-rights-windows-10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time
keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
time.sleep(0.3)

keyboard.type("cmd")
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press(Key.right)
keyboard.release(Key.right)
keyboard.press(Key.down)
keyboard.release(Key.down)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
time.sleep(0.5)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is here**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746382/7352806

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'
if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)
    sys.exit(0)
```