# Drop/delete folder with different credentials

Tags: python, shutil

I am using the `shutil` module to delete a folder of windows7, however I would need Python to delete the folder using different credentials from the ones currently using the machine. Is it possible to set it to somehow the delete with different credentials?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script ?

Answer (score 0):

Run the python script using Windows Task Scheduler; there it's possible to run the code using different credentials.