# Send image as a JSON with Pytest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have a DRF `POST` endpoint that accepts some data + image, my question is how  can I test this endpoint using something like **Pytest**, I'm facing a prob with sending images as a `JSON`, I tried to use PIL but didn't work.

**serializer**

```py
class CreateCategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=500, required=False)
    priority = serializers.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = serializers.ImageField()
```

**test**

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_name_exist(authenticate_superuser, category):
    data = {
        "title": "CAT 1",
        "description": "Description", 
        "priority": 20,
        "image": "??" 
    }

    response = authenticate_superuser.post(reverse('category_admin:create'), data=data)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    assert response.data['detail'] == 'This title already exists'
```

Comment: That begs a question... why would the endpoint receive images as JSON in the first place? That would be 33% inneficient.

Comment: What might be possible is to store the image as Base64 encoded, and then decode the image within the test.

Comment: Yeah, but keep in mind that encoding as Base64 would be 33% inneficient. There seems to be a design problem at the endpoint itself. It's not wise to send images as JSON.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Why is this inefficient? actually, it works fine with the react as a front-end, anyway I would like to hear your suggestion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework - Unit test image file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641595/django-rest-framework-unit-test-image-file-upload)

Comment: It's because JSON is a text format, while images are binary; that means that, in order to send images in a JSON, you would need to use some encoding to safely encode the binary to string; the most common way to encode a binary into a string is Base64, that works well, but increases the data's size by 33%.

Comment: See a list of pros and cons of sending images inside a JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279153/rest-api-file-ie-images-processing-best-practices

Comment: @2293980990 No, it's not

Comment: What went wrong when you used PIL? How did you try uploading the image? can you update the code?