# Python Changing IP Address using WMI

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, wmi, ipv4

I am attempting to use WMI to change the IP address of my PC.
The code below is run from the command line on Windows:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=1)
nic = c[1]
ip = "192.168.1.1"
subnetmask = "255.255.255.0"
nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip], SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
```

The above code then returns the following result:

```
(-2147024891,)
```

I believe this error is related to permissions.

When I run the command line as Administrator, and enter the above code again, I am presented with the value:

```
(0L,)
```

This value indicates that the IP change was successful.

Is there a way for me to change the IP address without first running the command line as Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get administrator rights from within the script, as is demonstrated  [in an other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930586/46172)