# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied for creating file

Tags: python-3.x, permissions, operating-system

I have been trying to make a file in C drive but I am getting PermissionError using python 3.6. How can I fix this problem?

```
import os

os.mkdir('C:\\Program Files\\test_folder')
```

Comment: Create the folder somewhere else where you have permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify `C:\Program Files\`, you need administrator permissions. So this is not specifically a Python problem.

Run your program from an administrator user, for instance by right-clicking and selecting *Run as administrator* or using `runas` in the console. You may also need to [pass UAC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/130763/35070).

Comment: If this or any other answer solves your problem, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!