# Request UAC Elevation From Within Python Script With ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW

Tags: python, uac

myClass generates a XLSX file to the './output' folder. The following line of code in myClass requires administrator privilege:

```
excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

I followed the answer in 
[Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script), and now I have the following script:

```
import ctypes, sys
from my_module import myClass

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    myClass
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, "", None, 1)
```

However, this seems to elevate and exit, as if I selected No in the UAC prompt.

If I run the above code block in Administrator cmd, `>python uac_test.py`, somehow it generates 2 identical files, instead of one.

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe `myClass` WAS executed, but in a separate window/process so you didn't notice.

try using something like `input()` to see if another window was indeed open.