# Permission denied to access r”C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts”

Tags: python, python-3.x, host

so I have a problem trying to run this python code as administrator so I am not able to access and write on host file. Can anyone help me? I have looked through many of other questions but non of them seem to work.

**Host File Directory:**  C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts

(Such as)
[Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)

Some of these answers actually work on prompting to get administrator access, but it still doesn't give permission to my program. The only way I figured out is to run python shell as administrator first and then run the code or run the command prompt as administrator and open python file with command prompt.

**WEBSITE**

https://boostlog.io/@faisalnad/create-a-website-blocker-with-python-5afe86ff47018500491f4898

This program is made for blocking website.

```
import time 
from datetime import datetime as dt 

# change hosts path according to your OS 
hosts_path = r”C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts”
# localhost's IP 
redirect = "127.0.0.1"

# websites That you want to block 
website_list = ["www.facebook.com","facebook.com", 
      "dub119.mail.live.com","www.dub119.mail.live.com", 
      "www.gmail.com","gmail.com"] 

while True: 

    # time of your work 
    if dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,8)  < dt.now() < dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day,16): 
        print("Working hours...") 
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file: 
            content = file.read() 
            for website in website_list: 
                if website in content: 
                    pass
                else: 
                    # mapping hostnames to your localhost IP address 
                    file.write(redirect + " " + website + "\n") 
    else: 
        with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file: 
            content=file.readlines() 
            file.seek(0) 
            for line in content: 
                if not any(website in line for website in website_list): 
                    file.write(line) 

            # removing hostnmes from host file 
            file.truncate() 

        print("Fun hours...") 
    time.sleep(5)
```

**This is the error:**

```
Working hours...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Key\Desktop\random project.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(hosts_path, 'r+') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\etc\\hosts'
```

**FILE DIRECTORY**
[image]

Comment: Check if AV is running, it may be locking the `hosts` files, also make sure the script is running privileged. Note: `hosts_path` seems hard-coded and `c`  isn't always the default OS install drive. Remember to issue a `ipconfig /flushdns`after changing the hosts file. The project seems interesting! Blocking students from accessing social medial on study time?! great !

Answer (score 0):

You can add write permission for the user under which your program runs following [this link](https://windowsreport.com/access-denied-hosts-windows-10/#4) to add permission to the host file