# How to elevate to root within a python script?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, root, elevated-privileges

I am trying to write a python script which will ask for root permissions. I have tried using elevate for python (which supposedly shows a dialog box asking for a root or "admin" password), but it gave a "No such file or directory" error when I ran it.

```py
import os
from elevate import elevate

def is_root():
    return os.getuid() == 0

print("before ", is_root())
elevate()
print("after ", is_root())
```

Why does this happen? Are there any working alternatives that utilize the system GUI?
**EDIT**:
I am using Kubuntu 18 with Python 3.6, but I would like for it to work on Windows too.
**FURTHER EDIT:**
This is a question about dialog boxes (for basic/Windows users), not TUI.

Comment: What's `elevate`? What OS are you using?

Comment: elevate is a python library. i am on linux.

Comment: I'd guess that elevate is trying to use a tool from $PATH which you don't have. Try "strace -f -e trace=execve python3 script.py"?

Comment: Check this [github issue](https://github.com/barneygale/elevate/issues/3). It's a bug in this package.

Comment: There really is no such thing as a "system GUI" for privilege escalation under Linux. Individual desktop environments may have their own solution to this issue, but there is no standard API for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a full solution that works under Windows and Linux to elevate UAC or sudo to root, working whether the code is interpreted, frozen or compiled with Nuitka.

[EDIT]
Disclaimer: The code in this post is outdated.
**I have published the elevation code as a python package.**
Install with `pip install command_runner`

Usage:

```
from command_runner.elevate import elevate

def main():
    """My main function that should be elevated"""
    print("Who's the administrator, now ?")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    elevate(main)
```

[/EDIT]

The code basically checks if it's already elevated, if yes, runs main() function, if not, it spawns an elevated subprocess which will run main() function.

Hope it helps

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import logging

if os.name == 'nt':
    try:
        import ctypes
        # import ctypes  # In order to perform UAC check with ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW()
        import win32event  # monitor process
        import win32process  # monitor process
        from win32com.shell.shell import ShellExecuteEx
        from win32com.shell import shellcon
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError('Cannot import ctypes for checking admin privileges on Windows platform.')


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def main():
    # Your code goes here
    # Keep in mind that elevating under windows will not redirect stdout/stderr to the main process
    print('Hello, elevated world !')


def is_admin():
    """
    Checks whether current program has administrative privileges in OS
    Works with Windows XP SP2+ and most Unixes

    :return: Boolean, True if admin privileges present
    """
    current_os_name = os.name

    # Works with XP SP2 +
    if current_os_name == 'nt':
        try:
            return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() == 1
        except Exception:
            raise EnvironmentError('Cannot check admin privileges')
    elif current_os_name == 'posix':
        # Check for root on Posix
        return os.getuid() == 0
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('OS does not seem to be supported for admin check. OS: %s' % current_os_name)


# Improved answer I have done in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759083/2635443
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if is_admin():
        main(sys.argv)
    else:
        # UAC elevation / sudo code working for CPython, Nuitka >= 0.6.2, PyInstaller, PyExe, CxFreeze

        # Regardless of the runner (CPython, Nuitka or frozen CPython), sys.argv[0] is the relative path to script,
        # sys.argv[1] are the arguments
        # The only exception being CPython on Windows where sys.argv[0] contains absolute path to script
        # Regarless of OS, sys.executable will contain full path to python binary for CPython and Nuitka,
        # and full path to frozen executable on frozen CPython

        # Recapitulative table create with
        # (CentOS 7x64 / Python 3.4 / Nuitka 0.6.1 / PyInstaller 3.4) and
        # (Windows 10 x64 / Python 3.7x32 / Nuitka 0.6.2.10 / PyInstaller 3.4)
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # | OS  | Variable       | CPython                       | Nuitka               | PyInstaller                  |
        # |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
        # | Lin | argv           | ['./script.py', '-h']         | ['./test', '-h']     | ['./test.py', -h']           |
        # | Lin | sys.executable | /usr/bin/python3.4            | /usr/bin/python3.4   | /absolute/path/to/test       |
        # | Win | argv           | ['C:\\Python\\test.py', '-h'] | ['test', '-h']       | ['test', '-h']               |
        # | Win | sys.executable | C:\Python\python.exe          | C:\Python\Python.exe | C:\absolute\path\to\test.exe |
        # --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Nuitka 0.6.2 and newer define builtin __nuitka_binary_dir
        # Nuitka does not set the frozen attribute on sys
        # Nuitka < 0.6.2 can be detected in sloppy ways, ie if not sys.argv[0].endswith('.py') or len(sys.path) < 3
        # Let's assume this will only be compiled with newer nuitka, and remove sloppy detections
        try:
            # Actual if statement not needed, but keeps code inspectors more happy
            if __nuitka_binary_dir is not None:
                is_nuitka_compiled = True
        except NameError:
            is_nuitka_compiled = False

        if is_nuitka_compiled:
            # On nuitka, sys.executable is the python binary, even if it does not exist in standalone,
            # so we need to fill runner with sys.argv[0] absolute path
            runner = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
            arguments = sys.argv[1:]
            # current_dir = os.path.dirname(runner)

            logger.debug('Running elevator as Nuitka with runner [%s]' % runner)
            logger.debug('Arguments are %s' % arguments)

        # If a freezer is used (PyInstaller, cx_freeze, py2exe)
        elif getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
            runner = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
            arguments = sys.argv[1:]
            # current_dir = os.path.dirname(runner)

            logger.debug('Running elevator as Frozen with runner [%s]' % runner)
            logger.debug('Arguments are %s' % arguments)

        # If standard interpreter CPython is used
        else:
            runner = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
            arguments = [os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])] + sys.argv[1:]
            # current_dir = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])

            logger.debug('Running elevator as CPython with runner [%s]' % runner)
            logger.debug('Arguments are %s' % arguments)

        if os.name == 'nt':
            # Re-run the program with admin rights
            # Join arguments and double quote each argument in order to prevent space separation
            arguments = ' '.join('"' + arg + '"' for arg in arguments)
            try:
                # Old method using ctypes which does not wait for executable to exit nor deos get exit code
                # See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew
                # int 0 means SH_HIDE window, 1 is SW_SHOWNORMAL
                # needs the following imports
                # import ctypes

                # ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, 'runas', runner, arguments, None, 0)

                # Metthod with exit code that waits for executable to exit, needs the following imports
                # import ctypes  # In order to perform UAC check
                # import win32event  # monitor process
                # import win32process  # monitor process
                # from win32com.shell.shell import ShellExecuteEx
                # from win32com.shell import shellcon

                childProcess = ShellExecuteEx(nShow=0, fMask=shellcon.SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS,
                                              lpVerb='runas', lpFile=runner, lpParameters=arguments)
                procHandle = childProcess['hProcess']
                obj = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(procHandle, -1)
                exit_code = win32process.GetExitCodeProcess(procHandle)
                logger.debug('Child exited with code: %s' % exit_code)
                sys.exit(exit_code)

            except Exception as e:
                logger.info(e)
                logger.debug('Trace', exc_info=True)
                sys.exit(255)
        # Linux runner and hopefully Unixes
        else:
            # Search for sudo executable in order to avoid using shell=True with subprocess
            sudo_path = None
            for path in os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(':'):
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, 'sudo')):
                    sudo_path = os.path.join(path, 'sudo')
            if sudo_path is None:
                logger.error('Cannot find sudo executable. Cannot elevate privileges. Trying to run wihtout.')
                main(sys.argv)
            else:
                command = 'sudo "%s"%s%s' % (
                    runner,
                    (' ' if len(arguments) > 0 else ''),
                    ' '.join('"%s"' % argument for argument in arguments)
                )
                try:
                    output = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                                                     shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
                    output = output.decode('unicode_escape', errors='ignore')

                    logger.info('Child output: %s' % output)
                    sys.exit(0)
                except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
                    exit_code = exc.returncode
                    logger.error('Child exited with code: %s' % exit_code)
                    try:
                        output = exc.output.decode('unicode_escape', errors='ignore')
                        logger.error('Child outout: %s' % output)
                    except Exception as exc:
                        logger.debug(exc, exc_info=True)
                    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

Comment: On Linux/Unix change ```for path in os.environ.get('PATH', ''):``` to ```for path in os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(':'):```

Comment: Thanks. Code is quite old that is actually fixed in the PyPI package I posted. Edited the post to point to the package with updated code. Thanks for proofreading.

Answer (score 3):

Since your working on Linux, graphical prompts are tried before sudo by default. You should therefore disable the graphical prompts by using the following command:

```
elevate(graphical=False)
```

This Solution worked for me and is quite simple.

Source: https://pypi.org/project/elevate/

Comment: Sorry it was unclear, I just edited my question to be more concise. The issue is getting a graphical prompt, not an in-terminal one.