# Python: Getting Pydub to work with OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory and OSError: [WinError 740] errors

Tags: python, windows, pydub

I am trying to get `pydub` package to work. I installed `pydub` and `ffmpeg`. When I run my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3('Q001007.mp3')
```

I get the following error:

```
> OSError: [WinError 740] The requested operation requires elevation
```

I am not sure how to solve this error or why it is happening.  I checked a solution in another post [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script?) but the solution there did not work. Is there an easier way to get pydub to work?

Comment: What you tried to do to elevate permissions doesn't make any sense in this case. It's code that would be used to run some other script: it will not continue to execute the rest of your code in the manner you expect (this is why just copy/pasting stuff without understanding it is dangerous). I don't know what pydub is trying to do that requires elevated permissions, but you probably got a traceback and it would help if you instead posted the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

To get Pydub to work on Windows:

(1) Install [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)

(2) Install [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) following the instruction in [this video](https://youtu.be/SW-iKrT_nJs) to add `ffmpeg` to your path.

(3) If `ffmpeg` has an administrator permission, remove it by right clicking on each `exe` file in `ffmpeg\bin`; and select `Properties`; and from `Compatibility` make sure that `Run the program as administrator` is not selected.

(4) Then restart your computer. This is a very important step.