# The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator) python 3 - windows 10

Tags: python

I want to execute this command (`"netsh wlan export profile folder=c:\ key=clear"`)
in cmd via python 3 in windows 10 to get my wifi passwords so I create a script like that

```
import os
print(os.popen("netsh wlan export profile folder=c:\ key=clear").read())
```

but the code gives my this error
The requested operation requires elevation (Run as administrator)

I want to make the script run as administrator

but I want to make it show a message From User Account Control that tells me

Do You Want To Allow This App To Make Changes To Your Device
                YES           NO

but I want to do that Via Python Code

Comment: See if this link - [Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script) provides some clarity.

Comment: the link isn't useful

Answer (score 1):

For one off runs set your bench to run as administrator. Say you use Pycharm. Then open Pycharm as administrator.

For other one offs make a shortcut to your command line and set the shortcut to use administrator.

Answer (score 1):

you cant get administrations privilege for security purpose

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).