# Automation of uninstalling a Windows Application

Tags: python, uninstallation, pywinauto, rpa

I am trying to uninstall an application named BlueStacks App Player on Windows using the Vasily Ryabov example of 7z uninstall.

I'm getting the error:

> C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>
> C:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/untitled1/uninstall_software.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/ADMIN/PycharmProjects/untitled1/uninstall_software.py", line
>   5, in 
>       explorer = pywinauto.Application().connect(path='explorer.exe')   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 1005, in connect
>       self.__warn_incorrect_bitness()   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 1083, in __warn_incorrect_bitness
>       if self.backend.name == 'win32' and self.is64bit() != is_x64_Python():   File
>   "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py",
>   line 1098, in is64bit
>       return handleprops.is64bitprocess(self.process)   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py",
>   line 183, in is64bitprocess
>       phndl = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, 0, process_id) pywintypes.error: (87, 'OpenProcess', 'The parameter is
>   incorrect.')
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

The code is :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pywinauto

pywinauto.Application().start(r'explorer.exe')
explorer = pywinauto.Application().connect(path='explorer.exe')

# Go to "Control Panel -> Programs and Features"
NewWindow = explorer.window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, class_name='CabinetWClass')
try:
    NewWindow.AddressBandRoot.ClickInput()
    NewWindow.TypeKeys(r'Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
    ProgramsAndFeatures = explorer.window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, title='Programs and Features', class_name='CabinetWClass')

    # wait while list of programs is loading
    explorer.WaitCPUUsageLower(threshold=5)

    item_7z = ProgramsAndFeatures.FolderView.GetItem('BlueStacks App Player')
    item_7z.EnsureVisible()
    item_7z.ClickInput(button='right', where='icon')
    explorer.PopupMenu.MenuItem('Uninstall').Click()

    Confirmation = explorer.window_(title='Programs and Features', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if Confirmation.Exists():
        Confirmation.Yes.ClickInput()
        Confirmation.WaitNot('visible')

    WindowsInstaller = explorer.window_(title='Windows Installer', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if WindowsInstaller.Exists():
        WindowsInstaller.WaitNot('visible', timeout=20)

    SevenZipInstaller = explorer.window_(title='BlueStacks App Player', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if SevenZipInstaller.Exists():
        SevenZipInstaller.WaitNot('visible', timeout=20)

    if 'BlueStacks App Player' not in ProgramsAndFeatures.FolderView.Texts():
        print('OK')
finally:
    NewWindow.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must start the script as Administrator. UAC confirmation can't be automated by OS design (for security reason). So you have to disable UAC first, then follow this answer to restart the script as Administrator:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930586/3648361

Comment: I'm still getting this error : `pywintypes.error: (87, 'OpenProcess', 'The parameter is incorrect.')`  It's opening the explorer window and nothing happens after that.

Comment: Running script as Administrator means "right click on the script and choose "run as Administrator" menu item". User can be in admin group, but default running mode is not as Administrator. The same can be done for `cmd.exe` or set in the shortcut properties to always run as Admin.