# How to run a script with admin privileges to kill a process?

Tags: python, windows, cmd, admin, taskkill

I'm trying to run a python script to kill a process, but I need admin rights. I tried using `runas /profile /savecred /user:domain\user "taskkill /f /im myprocess.exe"` but it didn't work. My user has admin rights on the system (windows).

I know the script works, because I have tested it in the Admin CMD window.

Also, I tested the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script) but I am asked to run python and I need to bypass this UAC request.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: are you in company network or domain?

Comment: Yes, it is a company domain

Comment: so you will never be able to run admin right unless you ask your administrator or you hack the server :-)

Comment: Even if my user is part of the Administrator group?

Comment: its about your permissions in the AD, not about your target, so it is impossible unless you got the admin pwd. also admin will get an alert so if you are trying smthg bad, i suggest you to forget it!