# How do I run a script with elevated UAC permissions using ctypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, windows-10, user-account-control

I'm attempting to create a utility tool via Python 3.x for the Windows 10 command-line. Since it will better format general command-line commands into more user-friendly menus, I want it to require elevated permissions through UAC when it runs.

I'm using the `ctypes` method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930586/10117098), and it does indeed have Python's executable request UAC elevation.

However, since a lot of the things I'll be writing menus and the like for will require (or be heavily limited without) these elevated permissions, I want the script to exit (preferably through `sys.exit`) if it doesn't find any.

In the `ctypes` method I mentioned, it should run as follows;

1. It defines a function `is_admin()`, which gets the value of `ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()`, and if it's 0, returns false instead.
2. `is_admin()` is called in a conditional, and if it gets false, it attempts to execute the command-line command to re-run the script as an executable using `ShellExecuteW` and some variables from `sys`;

   ```
   ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv[0]), None, 1)
   ```

In my code, I have the above conditional with the addition of a variable `elevReq` that I set to true;

```py
if is_admin():
    success("Already running as administrator!") # "success" and "warn" are defined earlier
    elevReq = True
else:
    warn("Requesting administrative permissions...", False)
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv[0]), None, 1)
    elevReq = True
```

I follow it up with another conditional that checks to see if `elevReq` is true and `is_admin()` is false, to see if the user selected "no" on UAC's pop-up -- if it is, it *should* throw an error about the lack of elevated privileges, and then quit;

```py
if elevReq and is_admin() == False:
    error("[FATAL] Elevation was not given! Stopping...", True)
    sys.exit(1)
```

The problem I'm having is that the given method doesn't seem to actually be elevating permissions of Python. UAC does pop up, but when any option is selected, it doesn't seem to matter, as the above condition fires anyway. Manually running the script in an elevated command prompt from the start doesn't have this issue.

Is this an issue with the script not re-loading when it should? If not, why is it exiting anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ShellExecute API call will spawn a new process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#:%7E:text=Launches%20an%20application%20as%20Administrator), it won't elevate permissions for the current process running.

Let's analyze this code snippet:

```py
if is_admin():
    main()
else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
```

When you first run this Python script without privileges, this *initial* process will jump to the last line of the code because `is_admin` returns `False`. Once there, the UAC prompt is displayed.

- If the UAC prompt is accepted, then a *completely new* process (with different process ID) is created and the code is executed again (from the beginning), but this time with admin privileges. Now `is_admin` should return `True` and `main` should be called.
- If the UAC prompt is rejected, no new process is created.

Regardless of the UAC response, the *initial* process will get the [return code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#return-value) back, but its privileges will remain unaltered.

If you want to try this yourself, add an `input()` at the end of the file and you should be able to see two different windows after accepting the UAC prompt.

To avoid having your code being executed twice be sure to keep everything inside the `main` function. If you want to take an action based on the return code, this only makes sense for failures (code <= 32). If the return code is successfull (> 32), then the process should end gracefully and let the new spawned process do its job.

Comment: that's the issue, then; it doesn't seem to be doing anything with that new process. i can see it being made in Task Manager, but it doesn't appear to be running any new windows or command prompt/PowerShell instances. i've tried running it both in a standalone command prompt window, and in the built-in PowerShell prompt that Visual Studio Code provides.

Comment: so, i just tried to modify the `lpFile` and `lpParameters` arguments to run `cmd /k <python.exe> <script>` rather than just python and the script, but no CMD prompt was made as it should have with the `/k` parameter, meaning that the new process isn't being presented visually at all. this is vital for my code as it's supposed to be a utility to aid in using the prompt.

Comment: Try using `ShellExecuteEx` with `nShow=SW_SHOW`, maybe? That's what I used and I can see the prompt of my new process.

Comment: i can't seem to find any documentation on ShellExecuteEx to implement it -- all i'm finding on Microsoft's side is ShellExecuteA, W, or ExA and W (the final two being vastly different) -- regardless, both A and W have the `nCmdShow` parameter anyway so i gave it a try, but still have no such luck on it actually restarting the script in a new process.

Comment: `nShowCmd` is the sixth parameter of the call. In my example, 1 means `SW_NORMAL`. You can check all the possible values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow). I don't think that's the cause of your problem though.

Comment: If you run JUST the code snippet (remove all your own code) and call `input` in the `main` function, does it open the new window for you after accepting the UAC prompt?

Comment: it seems to appear for a very split second, but doesn't show any past that, and definitely doesn't stay put when `input` is called. might this be an issue specifically with ctypes' use of ShellExecuteW, somehow? i feel this issue is unique based on the answers so far

Comment: Do you have any other code inside the `main` function besides calling `input()`? What you describe seems like the code is raising an exception

Comment: nope, i made an entirely new script file, imported sys and ctypes, and made a completely different main function that holds only print and the input function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240311/discussion-between-earthtoaccess-and-martin-de-la-fuente).

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
import sys
import platform

def admin() -> "Admin Bool":
    """Requests UAC Admin on Windows with a prompt"""
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
            None,
            'runas',
            sys.executable,
            ' '.join(sys.argv),
            None,
            None
        )
        
        try:
            return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
        
        except:
            return False
        
    else:
        raise OSError("admin() only works for windows.")
```

This will request admin with an admin prompt.
If `True` is returned, then admin has been granted by the user. Else, `False` will be returned.

Comment: This is the same method I mentioned before, minor exception that, this time, it's all in the same function. The problem isn't that UAC isn't popping up, it's that even after it does, permissions still don't seem to be given. Even with the code formatted like this, it's still returning False and running the code for if it does (the final code block).