# Python winerror 5 access is denied using winreg - how to run Python file as admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry, administrator, winreg

```py
import winreg

path = winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

software = winreg.OpenKeyEx(path, r'HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0\\')

winreg.SetValueEx(software, 'ProcessorNameString', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, 'Intel(R)')

if software:

    winreg.CloseKey(software)
```

It gives me a WinError 5 when I run this code.

How can I get administrator access to this file using a Python module or script, as it needs to run with elevation?

Comment: Did you try running this script with administrative privileges? Otherwise, if you are trying to run with admin privileges from the script itself, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300494/how-do-i-run-a-script-with-elevated-uac-permissions-using-ctypes#:~:text=Let%27s%20analyze%20this%20code%20snippet%3A) to spawn a new process to run the same script with admin privileges if not already running as admin.